# Reuse same view across modules

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

This question is specific to Orchard CMS.

I have a partial view defined in a shared project. This partial view i would like to include in all the display views defined in other modules.

e.g Let's say I have a partial view with a label "Copyright information" defined in project "Shared".
I add a new module in Orchard, in Display view i would like to include this view. Copyright label is just an example, my requirement is to reuse form elements across modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own shapes, then create templates for them in the views directory of your module. Other modules can then reuse those shapes if they take a dependency on the first module. They can even override templates if they need to. Your theme can also override templates.

Comment: I added those common partial views in Theme's Views folder and it's working fine. Thanks.

Comment: Just one question regarding Model passed to those partial views. I am getting below error :The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Orchard.UI.Zones.ZoneHolding', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MyModelClass'. As an workaround I made the model type in partial views as dynamic and then casted it back to my model type. it worked. But Could you please tell me why this is happening?

Comment: @SaurabhA I came across the same issue as you were having and was stuck for a couple days.  I created a stackoverflow for your comment and finally have a solution. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32599119/2324708)