# Error Creating Custom ContentPart Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, orchardcms

I am getting the error **"The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Orchard.UI.Zones.ZoneHolding', but this dictionary requires a model item of type'First.Module.Models.PersonListPart'"**, when entering the editor page for the content in the admin dashboard.

My content driver looks like:

```
    public class PersonListPartDriver : ContentPartDriver<PersonListPart> 
    {


         protected override DriverResult Display(
             PersonListPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper) {
             return ContentShape("Parts_PersonList",
                 () => shapeHelper.Parts_PersonList(
                        MaxCount: part.MaxCount
                     ));
         }


         protected override DriverResult Editor(
             PersonListPart part, dynamic shapeHelper) {
             return ContentShape("Parts_PersonList_Edit",
                 () => shapeHelper.EditorTemplate(
                     TemplateName: "Parts/PersonList",
                     Models: part,
                     Prefix: Prefix
));
         }

         //POST
         protected override DriverResult Editor(
             PersonListPart part, IUpdateModel updater, dynamic shapeHelper)
         {

             updater.TryUpdateModel(part, Prefix, null, null);
             return Editor(part, shapeHelper);
         }
     }
```

My PersonListPart Model looks like:

```
namespace First.Module.Models {

    public class PersonListPart : ContentPart<PersonListPartRecord> {
        public int MaxCount {
            get { return Record.MaxCount; }
            set { Record.MaxCount = value; }
        }
    }


    public class PersonListPartRecord : ContentPartRecord {
        public virtual int MaxCount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

It loads the Editor CSHTML for the content part which looks like:

```
@model First.Module.Models.PersonListPart

<fieldset>
    <legend>@T("Person List Settings")</legend>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MaxCount, T("Maximal count"));

            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MaxCount, new { @class = "text small" })
        </li>
    </ol>
</fieldset>
```

It is having an issue in particular with the @model.

When debugging and commenting out the @model, the Model.ContentItem.Part[0] has the item, but being new to Orchard CMS I am stumped how to use this correctly.

Comment: What does your PersonListPart look like?

Comment: @user3123386 added PersonListPart above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a typo in the **PersonListPartDriver** *Editor* Method.  Since the values in the EditorTemplate() are dynamic its easy to create a typo and in this case it created an error that was difficult to debug.

```
protected override DriverResult Editor(
      PersonListPart part, dynamic shapeHelper) {
          return ContentShape("Parts_PersonList_Edit",
                 () => shapeHelper.EditorTemplate(
                     TemplateName: "Parts/PersonList",
                     Models: part,
                     Prefix: Prefix
      ));
}
```

The fix

```
Models: part,
```

should be

```
Model: part,
```

Comment: Lol, made the exact same typo